# How to split HTML output into functions within the same ASPX page?

Tags: asp.net

In classic ASP, one was able to divide a complex HTML page into different methods in the same file, and call them from within the main HTML output, as below:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="leftside">
      <% Call WriteLeftSide %>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
      <% Call WriteRightSide %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<%

Sub LeftSide
  %> .. some HTML here <%
  Call CommonBottom
End Sub

Sub RightSide
  %> .. some other HTML here <%
  Call CommonBottom
End Sub

Sub CommonBottom
  %> .. some common HTML here <%
End Sub

%>
```

The above can be done within a single .ASP file. I'd like to do the same *within a single ASPX file*, in a similar manner as above, dividing the HTML eg. into functions or controls *within the same page* (same ASPX file), but I can't work out if this is possible.

How is this same classic ASP pattern accomplished *within a single ASPX file* (ie. without using ASCX files)?

Comment: With user controls. You defined a user control which represents some common piece of functionality and markup, and then use it on the page

Comment: @Andrei, I'm aware of that but usercontrols are *separate ascx files*. I'm asking how to accomplish the above in the *same* ASPX file, as stated.

Comment: you can call server side function using some thing like this                                        <div class="abc">
                <%= OutputEncoder.HtmlEncode(Explanation1)%>
  </div>. if this works for you i will post a working example

Comment: @ankur, Thanks but that requires returning a string, which is highly undesirable when constructing HTML - no intellisense, etc. Using `%> some html here <%` in classic ASP allowed switching to "html mode" in the IDE, to return HTML output within a function, which was easy and clean. Not possible in ASPX?